# React Native not rendering on prop change

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created the following component:

```
type ToggleButtonProps = { title: string, selected: boolean }
export default class ToggleButton extends Component<ToggleButtonProps>{
    render(){
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...this.props}>
                <View style={[style.button, this.props.selected ? style.buttonSelected : style.buttonDeselected]}>
                    <Text style={[style.buttonText, this.props.selected ? style.buttonTextSelected : style.buttonTextDeselected]}>{this.props.title}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
}
```

The styles are simple color definitions that would visually indicate whether a button is selected or not. From the parent component I call (item is my object):

`item.props.selected = true;`

I've put a breakpoint and I verify that it gets hit, `item.props` is indeed my item's props with a `selected` property, and it really changes from `false` to `true`.

However, nothing changes visually, neither do I get `render()` or `componentDidUpdate` called on the child.

What should I do to make the child render when its props change? (I am on React Native 0.59.3)

Comment: I'm guessing props.selected will be toggled based on UI events or actions, so you should use `state` instead as it is perfect for that use case

Comment: @TyroHunter I've also thought that, but after some search I still can't find how to `setState` of the child from parent dynamically.

Comment: How you do it is assign `selected` to the parent's state instead. Once you call setState and toggle the value, the components `render` will be called, in your case the parent's. Which will cause the child to re-render as well, hence `ToggleButton` is inside parents render. Lastly, pass the state value to the child `<ToggleButton {...this.state}` (your ToggleButton code is already fine)

Comment: @TyroHunter I don't change anything in parent's state, it even doesn't have any state. It's just a wrapper of multiple `ToggleButton`s.

Comment: Okay that's a helpful information. I am thinking you want each toggle buttons state to be stored in the parent state, correct?

Comment: @TyroHunter well, I was thinking that each button will have its own selected state, and when one is selected all the others will be deselected. (as this is my requirement at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the child component by literally assigning to props like this:

`item.props.selected = true;`

However, there are many ways to re-render the child components. But I think the solution below would be the easiest one.

*You want to have a container or **smart component** which will keep the states or data of each toggle buttons in one place. Because mostly likely, this component will potentially need to call an api to send or process that data.*

If the number of toggle buttons is fixed you can simply have the state like so:

```
state = {
  buttonOne: {
    id: `buttonOneId`,
    selected: false,
    title: 'title1'
  },
  buttonTwo: {
    id: `buttonTwoId`,
    selected: false,
    title: 'title2'
  },
}
```

Then create a method in the parent which will be called by each child components action `onPress`:

```
onButtonPress = (buttonId) => {
  this.setState({
    [buttonId]: !this.state[buttonId].selected // toggles the value
  }); // calls re-render of each child
}
```

pass the corresponding values to each child as their props in the render method:

```
render() {
  return (
     <View>
       <ToggleButton onPressFromParent={this.onButtonPress} dataFromParent={this.state.buttonOne} />
       <ToggleButton onPressFromParent={this.onButtonPress} dataFromParent={this.state.buttonTwo} />
       ...
```

finally each child can use the props:

```
  ...
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.onPressFromParent(this.props.dataFromParent.id)}>
    <View style={[style.button, this.props.dataFromParent.selected ? style.buttonSelected : style.buttonDeselected]}>
  ...
```

*I left the `title` field intentionally for you to try and implement.*

P.S: You should be able to follow the code as these are just JS or JSX.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Great answer. While the number of my buttons isn't fixed, the answer gives me an insight as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Because children do not rerender if the props of the parent change, but if its STATE changes :)

Update child to have attribute 'key' equal to "selected" (example based on reactjs tho')

```
Child {
  render() {
    return <div key={this.props.selected}></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to bind the key to a variable.

Comment: variable? you will have to put it on some div(or whatever it is on react native).

Comment: I don't get why I should be assiging some sort of property value to the key attribute.

Comment: just try it and let me know because your component won't rerender on props change. they rerender when THEIR STATE changes